# Limit readable text with a 'read more' link?

Tags: text, limit

I am having this issue how to make a limit readable text with a 'read more' link below it. I am making my own cms system as a school project, so i would like to add that feature to it.

I have made so i am able to create an article, but the text just keep going on if i write like 1000 words in one article. I only have a little clue how to make the text limit to 50-100 words.

Anyone have made this before that could help me out how they did it?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Have you tried anything?

Comment: php. This is how it echo my text out from the database
                                                  
  echo '<p>'. $row['besked'] . '</p>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to have two methods `GetPreview(id, n)` and `GetArticle(id)` where the first returns only first `n` words from an `Article` with a link to a page that calls second method.

Assuming that `$articleText` is the content of your article and a *word* is considered to be delimited by spaces this is how a part of the `GetPreview` function will look like:

```
$words = explode(" ", $articleText);
if (count($words) <= $n)
   return $articleText; //unchanged

$preview = array_splice($words, 0, $n); //n is the number of words
return implode(" ", $preview) . "... <br />" .
<a href=\"ViewArticle.php?id=" . $articleId . "\">Read More </a>";
```

where `ViewArticle.php` should be another page that loads the entire article. 
However, this is an example that will work for plain text articles. If your articles contain HTML the method to extract the preview becomes more complex because you don't want it break the content in the middle of a HTML tag.

Another approach, which is actually safer and used in popular CMS like WordPress is to *decorate* your article with a specific HTML comment like:

```
<!-- more -->
```

When you display the entire article you don't have to do anything special because this will not be displayed by the browser (remember, it's a comment).

However, in your `GetPreview` method you search for this string and if you find it:

- you get the text before it
- you append a 'Read More' link that redirects you to the full article

There are multiple advantages of this method:

- you can safely use HTML in your article.
- the author has full control on how the preview looks like.

Comment: So if you were echo'ing an article like this out foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { echo '<p>'. $row['besked'] . '</p>'; } . What would you prefer to use to limit the text and make a 'read more' link?